# Create a generic function that creates stacked dataset using d3

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have this dataset:

```js
const dataset = [
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "red", value: 10 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "blue", value: 20 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "gold", value: 30 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "green", value: 40 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "red", value: 5 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "blue", value: 15 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "gold", value: 25 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "green", value: 35 }
];
```

And I need to create a stacked barchart. To do that I used the d3 `stack()` function.
The result I need is this:

```js
const stackedDataset = [
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "red", value: 10, start: 0, end: 10 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "red", value: 5, start: 0, end: 5 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "blue", value: 20, start: 10, end: 30 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "blue", value: 15, start: 5, end: 20 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "gold", value: 30, start: 30, end: 60 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "gold", value: 25, start: 20, end: 45 },
  { date: "2022-01-01", category: "green", value: 40, start: 60, end: 100 },
  { date: "2022-01-02", category: "green", value: 35, start: 45, end: 80 }
]
```

So the same data but with a `start` and `end` property computed by d3.

I created a function that takes in input `dataset` and returns `stackedDataset`:

```js
export function getStackedSeries(dataset: Datum[]) {
  const categories = uniq(dataset.map((d) => d[CATEGORY])) as string[];
  const datasetGroupedByDateFlat = flatDataset(dataset);
  const stackGenerator = d3.stack().keys(categories);
  const seriesRaw = stackGenerator(
    datasetGroupedByDateFlat as Array<Dictionary<number>>
  );
  const series = seriesRaw.flatMap((serie, si) => {
    const category = categories[si];
    const result = serie.map((s, sj) => {
      return {
        [DATE]: datasetGroupedByDateFlat[sj][DATE] as string,
        [CATEGORY]: category,
        [VALUE]: datasetGroupedByDateFlat[sj][category] as number,
        start: s[0] || 0,
        end: s[1] || 0
      };
    });
    return result;
  });
  return series;
}

export function flatDataset(
  dataset: Datum[]
): Array<Dictionary<string | number>> {
  if (dataset.length === 0 || !DATE) {
    return (dataset as unknown) as Array<Dictionary<string | number>>;
  }
  const columnToBeFlatValues = uniqBy(dataset, CATEGORY).map(
    (d) => d[CATEGORY]
  );
  const datasetGroupedByDate = groupBy(dataset, DATE);
  const datasetGroupedByMainCategoryFlat = Object.entries(
    datasetGroupedByDate
  ).map(([date, datasetForDate]) => {
    const categoriesObject = columnToBeFlatValues.reduce((acc, value) => {
      const datum = datasetForDate.find(
        (d) => d[DATE] === date && d[CATEGORY] === value
      );
      acc[value] = datum?.[VALUE];
      return acc;
    }, {} as Dictionary<string | number | undefined>);
    return {
      [DATE]: date,
      ...categoriesObject
    };
  });
  return datasetGroupedByMainCategoryFlat as Array<Dictionary<string | number>>;
}
```

As you can see, the functions are specific for `Datum` type. Is there a way to modify them to make them works for a generic type `T` that has at least the three fields `date, category, value`?

I mean, I would like to have something like this:

```js
interface StackedStartEnd {
  start: number
  end: number
}

function getStackedSeries<T>(dataset: T[]): T extends StackedStartEnd
```

Obviously this piece of code should be refactored to make it more generic:

```js
{
  [DATE]: ...,
  [CATEGORY]: ...,
  [VALUE]: ...,
  start: ...,
  end: ...,
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-type-7gepl9?file=/src/index.ts:45-503) the working code.

I'm not a TypeScript expert so I need some help. Honestly what I tried to do was to modify the function signature but I failed and, anyway, I would like to make the functions as generic as possible and I don't know how to start.
Do I need to pass to the functions also the used columns names?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to make a more generic approach as you suggest mixing the two functions. By default, seems like your `getStackedSeries` function does not need to know about `date` and `category` properties, you can use a Generic Type to ensure just the `value` property, as we need to know that to calculate `start` and `end` values.

The full implementation can be viewed [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-type-forked-m3ey5r?file=/src/utils.ts:82-663).

```
export function getStackedSeries<T extends Datum>(
  data: T[],
  groupByProperty: PropertyType<T>
) {
  const groupedData = groupBy(data, (d) => d[groupByProperty]);

  const acumulatedData = Object.entries(groupedData).flatMap(
    ([_, groupedValue]) => {
      let acumulator = 0;

      return groupedValue.map(({ value, ...rest }) => {
        const obj = {
          ...rest,
          value: value,
          start: acumulator,
          end: acumulator + value
        };

        acumulator += value;

        return obj;
      });
    }
  );

  return acumulatedData;
}
```

The `getStackedSeries()` now receives a `data` property that extends `Datum` type, which is:

```
export interface Datum {
  value: number;
}
```

With that and a second property called `groupByProperty` we can define the groupBy clause and return all flatten by `flatMap`.

You probably notice that the return type now is defined by typescript dynamically by the use of a generic `<T>`. For example:

```
const dataGroupedByDate: (Omit<{
    date: string;
    category: string;
    value: number;
}, "value"> & {
    value: number;
    start: number;
    end: number;
})[]
```

You can also type this part of the function, but makes sense to let the compiler works for you and generate the types automatically based on input.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by date for start/end and take another grouping by category for the result set.

```js
const
    dataset = [{ date: "2022-01-01", category: "red", value: 10 }, { date: "2022-01-01", category: "blue", value: 20 }, { date: "2022-01-01", category: "gold", value: 30 }, { date: "2022-01-01", category: "green", value: 40 }, { date: "2022-01-02", category: "red", value: 5 }, { date: "2022-01-02", category: "blue", value: 15 }, { date: "2022-01-02", category: "gold", value: 25 }, { date: "2022-01-02", category: "green", value: 35 }],
    result = Object
        .values(dataset
            .reduce((r, { date, category, value }) => {
                const
                    start = r.date[date]?.at(-1).end ?? 0,
                    end = start + value,
                    object = { date, category, value, start, end };

                (r.date[date] ??= []).push(object);
                (r.category[category] ??= []).push(object);
                return r;
            }, { date: {}, category: {} })
            .category
        )
        .flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```